# md-select not updating from model of key value param

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a predefined model that I am using with an md-select (selectedVegetables). It doesn't seem to work with my model when it already has a key and value..   [Code Pen](http://codepen.io/hamsaya/pen/mWeXzW?editors=1010)

Check:

```
$scope.vegetables = 
    [{"key":"1","value":"Banana"},{"key":"2","value":"Apple"}];
$scope.selectedVegetables = [{"key":"1","value":"Apple"}];
```

in my controller.

and My html

```
   <md-input-container>
    <label>Vegetables</label>
    <md-select ng-model="selectedVegetables" md-on-close="clearSearchTerm()" data-md-container-class="selectdemoSelectHeader" multiple="">
      <md-select-header class="demo-select-header">
        <input ng-model="searchTerm" placeholder="Search for a vegetable.." class="demo-header-searchbox md-text" type="search">
      </md-select-header>
      <md-optgroup label="vegetables">
        <md-option ng-value="vegetable" ng-repeat="vegetable in vegetables |
          filter:searchTerm">{{vegetable}}</md-option>
      </md-optgroup>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. 
The solution is to add this to md-select

```
ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.key'}"
```